# What's the most efficient way to evaluate if a string is a palindrome using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and wrote the code below to determine if a string is a palindrome. I'm curious as to what is the most efficient way to accomplish the same task.

```
var isPalindrome = function (string) {
    var leftString = [];
    var rightString = [];

    // Remove spaces in the string and convert to an array
    var strArray = string.split(" ").join("").split("");    
    var strLength = strArray.length;

    // Determine if the string is even or odd in length, then assign left and right strings accordingly
    if (strLength % 2 !== 0) {
        leftString = strArray.slice(0, (Math.round(strLength / 2) - 1));
        rightString = strArray.slice(Math.round(strLength / 2), strLength);
    } else {
        leftString = strArray.slice(0, (strLength / 2));
        rightString = strArray.slice((strLength / 2, strLength))
    }

    if (leftString.join("") === rightString.reverse().join("")) {
        alert(string + " is a palindrome.");
    } else {
        alert(string + " is not a palindrome.")
    }

}


isPalindrome("nurses run");
```

Comment: Firebug has javascript profiling tools.  Try a few different approaches and see what performance you get.

Comment: If you're concerned with performance, search "jsperf palindrome", which gives you something like [this](http://jsperf.com/is-palindrome/3)

Comment: This sounds like homework.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear if you're talking about efficiency in terms of code length, or amount of computation, but this should be fairly good in both regards. And it takes into account non-alpha characters beside spaces as well as capitalization:

```
function isPalindrome(str) {
   var i, len;

   str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g, '');
   len = str.length;

   for(i = 0; i < len / 2; i += 1) {
      if(str.charCodeAt(i) != str.charCodeAt(len - i - 1)) {
         return false;
      }
   }

   return true;
}
```

A much shorter approach (though perhaps more computation intensive):

```
function isPalindrome(str) {
   str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g, '');

   return str == str.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

And if you really want that alert stuff, I'd suggest putting it in a separate function:

```
function isPalindromeAlert(str) {
  alert(str + "is " + (isPalindrome(str) ? "" : "not ") + "a palindrome.");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function isPalindrome( s )
{
   var i = 0, j = s.length-1;
   while( i < j )
       if( s[i++].toLowerCase() != s[j--].toLowerCase() ) return false;
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this one is lot simpler:

```
var isPalindrome = function (string) {
    if (string == string.split('').reverse().join('')) {
        alert(string + ' is palindrome.');
    }
    else {
        alert(string + ' is not palindrome.');
    }
}
```

See more: [Palindrome check in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813369/palindrome-check-javascript)

Comment: I don't think it is efficient to split, reverse, and join.

Comment: How does this even work?  I don't understand how the splitting, reversing, and joining are working here.  Unless you are making assumptions about the input that are not obvious...

Comment: This also will always return true, the if statement never compares the string to anything, it just checks that you are able to reverse the string

Comment: Shouldn't it be `string === string.split('').reverse().join('')`?

Comment: @asku What is the point of splitting and joining?  Cant you just reverse it and compare?

Comment: Also, this isn't efficient because the split, join, and reverse operations all take at least `n` operations, where `n` is the length of the string.  The two answers below all exit early as soon as they detect it is not a palindrome, so they will be more efficient.

Comment: I think `if (string == string.reverse())` is simpler and more efficient than this answer, but not as efficient as the other answers.

Comment: @Trenin, i can't. I must convert the string to array before `.reverse`. It can only used for arrays.

Comment: @asku - Fair enough.  Still not very efficient because you are doing lots of operations on the string, then array.  Better to loop through the characters of the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "abcba";
var len = str.Lenght;
var index = 0;

while(index <= len/2 && str[index] == str[len - index - 1]) index++;

if(index == len/2) {
    alert(string + " is a palindrome.");
}
else {
   alert(string + " is not a palindrome.");
}
```

You made a few unnecesary operations.

Answer (score 0):

To be efficient, you should avoid unnecessary computations.  Ask yourself:

- do you need to remove spaces?
- do you need to convert to an array?
- do you need to allocate new objects for the left and right strings?
- do you need to reverse the string?

The checking can be done in a very simple loop:

```
var len=string.length;
for (int i=0; i<(len/2); i++) {
  if (string[i] != string[len-i-1]) {
    alert(string + " is not a palindrome.");
    return;
  }
}
alert(string + " is a palindrome.");
```

To ignore spaces and non-alpha numeric characters, it can be re-written as follows:

```
function isAlphaNumeric( chr ) {
  return ( ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z')) ||
           ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z')) ||
           ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9')) );
}

// Note - template taken from @Matt's answer!
function isPalindrome( string ) {
  var i = 0, j = s.length-1;
  while( i < j ) {
    if (isAlphaNumeric(string[i])) {
      if (isAlphaNumeric(string[j])) {
        if ( string[i++].toLowerCase() != string[j--].toLowerCase() ) 
          return false;
      } else {
        j--;
      }
    } else {
      i++;
      if (!isAlphaNumeric(string[j])) j--;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Typically, a palindrome check should ignore spaces and other non-alpha characters.

Comment: @JLRishe Perhaps it is more efficient to skip over those characters inside the loop instead of creating entire intermediate objects...  For example, if the string is `a--------b`, then a new string `ab` is created after processing all `10` characters in the original string.  Only then is the check for palindromicity (is that a word?) done. This and some other answers would see on the first check that `'a'!='b'`, so would return immediately.

Comment: Ok, but I hope you enjoy coding that (and making sure it doesn't have any bugs). Typically, readable code is preferable to overwrought code with micro-optimizations.

Comment: @JLRishe OP asked for the most efficient way, not the most readable.  And I do enjoy coding that!

Answer (score 0):

unreadable + unmaintainable + terse + efficient + recursive + non-branching

```
function isPalindrome(s,i) {
 return (i=i||0)<0|| i>=s.length/2|| s[i]==s[s.length-1-i]&& isPalindrome(s,++i);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/namcx0yf/