# Javascript Palindrome Logic

Tags: javascript, palindrome

I have checked this thread: [Palindrome check in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813369/palindrome-check-in-javascript) But I'm more so looking to fix my own algorithm. I am just programming online right now so I do not have access to a good debugger. So any hints/debugging problems found would be greatly appreciated. Here's the code:

```
function isPalindrome(str) {
if(str !== null && str !== undefined && str !== NaN) {
 var strStripped = str.replace(/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()@]/g,"");
 var strSqueezed = strStripped.replace(/ /g, "");
 var i, k;
 k = str.length-1;
 var numOfValidComparisons = 0;
  for(i=0; i<strSqueezed.length; i++) {
   if(strSqueezed.charAt(i) === strSqueezed.charAt(k)) {
     numOfValidComparisons++;
   }
   k--;
  }
 if(numOfValidComparisons === strSqueezed.length)
   return true;
 else
   return false;
   }
  return false;
}
```

I've written down the loop comparison logic on paper and have been baffled momentarily. If you're unfamiliar with what a palindrome is here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome

The test I'm working with right now is this string `"race car"` (and looks great on paper)

Comment: `str.replace(/\W/g,"")==str.split("").reverse().join("").replace(/\W/g,"")`

Comment: Again, not looking for other answers I am looking to fix this one.

Comment: "I do not have access to a good debugger"... unless you're stuck in some ancient browser, what's wrong with the built-in console and associated tools? Chrome has an excellent debugger built in.

Comment: Also on a computer that doesn't allow saving to disk.. I'm not sure how to debug from code not saved on disk..

Comment: Overall this code is garbage haha. At least I got to this point though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
k = str.length-1;
```

should be

```
k = strSqueezed.length-1;
```

Thats it.

https://jsfiddle.net/aejmjsqk/

Comment: Lol. Thanks for the fresh eyes. I would have gotten it after lunch either way but thanks!