# Changing form input to JavaScript prompt

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, prompt

I have a function to check if a word entered in a text input is a palindrome:

```js
function Palindrome() {
  var revStr = "";
  var str = document.getElementById("str").value;
  var i = str.length;
  for (var j = i; j >= 0; j--) {
    revStr = revStr + str.charAt(j);
  }
  if (str == revStr) {
    alert(str + " is a palindrome");
  } else {
    alert(str + " is not a palindrome");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  Enter a String or Number:
  <input type="text" id="str" name="string" />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Check" onclick="Palindrome();" />
</form>
```

I would like the user to be prompted for a word, rather than entering a word into a text input, so I changed

```
var str = document.getElementById("str").value;
```

to

```
var str = prompt("Enter a string or number:")
```

But the prompt does not fire.
Why am I not being prompted for a word?

Comment: Remove the form and have `Palindrome();` after the closing `}` of your function to call the function. At the moment you're relying on the user clicking the button to run the function.

Comment: Also, [here's a slightly easier method to find out if a string is a palindrome](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14813569/1377002) that doesn't involve iteration.

Comment: So .. actually your question has nothing to do with palindromes and is in fact all about how to prompt the user to enter some text?  Why didn't you say so in the question title then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `Palindrome()` at the end of your script. As it currently stands, `Palindrome` only fires when you click `submit`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Palindrome() {
        var revStr = "";
        var str = prompt("Enter a string or number:")
        var i = str.length;
        for(var j=i; j>=0; j--) {
            revStr = revStr+str.charAt(j);
        }
        if(str == revStr) {
            alert(str+" is a palindrome");
        } else {
            alert(str+" is not a palindrome");
        }
    }
    Palindrome()
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qy6gyj1k/1/)

Comment: If this question helped you solve your problem, you should accept this answer. Learn more about [accepting answers here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the form if you're using a prompt, also there's a quick recursion way to find a palindrome (though not as efficient as the one referenced by Andy).  I added it to your (working version) just for reference.
Try this..

```
    function isPalindrome(x) {
        return x.length <= 1 ? true : (x.charAt(0) != x.charAt(x.length - 1) ? false : isPalindrome(x.slice(1, -1)))
    }

    function Palindrome(str) {

        var revStr = "";
       // var str = document.getElementById("str").value;
        var i = str.length;
        for(var j=i; j>=0; j--) {
            revStr = revStr+str.charAt(j);
        }

        if(str == revStr) {
            alert(str+" is a palindrome");
        } else {
            alert(str+" is not a palindrome");
        }
    }
    var str = prompt("Enter a string or number:")
    Palindrome(str)
    if (isPalindrome(str)){
        alert('isP: ' +str+" is a palindrome");

    } else{
        alert('isP: ' +str+" is not a palindrome");

    }
```