# JavaScript Palindrome

Tags: javascript, function, palindrome

I found a solution on how to write palindrome in StackOverFlow. This is the code snippet:

```
function palindrome(str) {
    var len = str.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < Math.floor(len/2); i++ ) {
        if (str[i] !== str[len - 1 - i]) {   //Problem in this line
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I understand every line except the one I have here. Can anyone please break it down for me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This function does not generate palindromes. It just checks if a string is one.

Comment: Could you explain what this part is meaning? str[len - 1 - i])

Comment: Sure, it gets character of a string at position `len - 1 - i`

Comment: you should check this link for a better solution [Javascript palindrome ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25091111/7804966)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop steps through the first half of the string, and it checks consecutive character to see if it is not equal (or not the same character)  to the next consecutive character on the other end of the string, starting from the end.

```
|0|1|2|3|4|
|l|e|v|e|l|

len = 5
```

This gives you:

```
str[i] !== str[len - 1 - i]
```

When `i = 0`, `str[i]` is l, which is equal to `str[5-1-0]`, which is `str[4]`, which also is l

Answer (score 0):

`str[i]` represents the (i+1)<sup>th</sup> character in *str*. If *str* is a palindrome then this character must be equal to the character that is *i* positions from the end of the string (by definition).

The last character in a string is at position *len - 1* (since *len* was defined as being the length of the string, and indexes start counting from 0). So you need to subtract *i* from that to arrive at the position where the character sits that should be the same as `str[i]`. Hence `str[len - 1 - i]`

The comparison is made with `!==`, i.e. not-equal. In that case we know for sure we do not have a palindrome and can exit with `false`.