# How does this line of code for checking whether a word is palindrome or not, work in JS?

Tags: javascript, palindrome

So I was going through solutions to find the fastest way to perform the operation of checking whether a word is palindrome or not in Javascript. I came across this as one of the solutions listed and it works, but I have no clue why the `` is used and how exactly it works. A detailed explanation would be welcome.

The code is as follows,

```
p=s=>s==[...s].reverse().join``
p('racecar'); //true
```

The link for the original answer is, 
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/35789680/5898523

Comment: isn't it obvious? :p throw the code in babel transpiler to see the ES5 version of events :p

Comment: *"find the fastest way"* – well it may be a succinct (ie clever) implementation but iterating over the input 3 times is certainly not going to be the *fastest* way.

Comment: Upon review of the answers, the one you've selected here is one of the slowest, btw. It's at least 20 times slower than [fastestIsPalindrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25091111/633183) provided by Jason Sebring. This is a perfect example of what goes wrong when you try to make code too clever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[tagged template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals_and_escape_sequences): without tagged template literals the sample would look like this:

```
p = s=>s==[...s].reverse().join('')
```

EDIT:

Looks like I answered before I read your question in full, sorry. [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) allow for placeholders that look like `${placeholder}`. ES6 runs the template through a built-in processor function to handle the placeholders, but you use your own custom function instead by using this 'tag' syntax:

```
tagFunction`literal ${placeholder} template`
```

The example code uses (abuses in my opinion) this functionality to save 2 characters by invoking the `join` method as a tag with an empty template.

Answer (score 0):

JS interprets it as the first argument for the join function, as otherwise it would join the string with the default ",". The part ".join``" equates to ".join('')", without having to add the two extra chars for the parentheses.

As to why exactly only `` works for this and not "" or '', you would have to look up the ECMA Script documentation; I don't have an explanation offhand for you.