# How do I create a palindrome checker?

Tags: javascript, palindrome

Here is the problem.
https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures-projects/palindrome-checker

My solution was

```
function palindrome(str) {{
let regex = /\W/g;
/\W/g.remove;
str.toLowerCase;
}
function reverseString(str) {
const reverseString = "";
for (let i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i++) {
  reverseString += str[i];
}
return reverseString;
}
if (str === reverseString) {
  return true;
}  return false;
}

palindrome("eye");
```

What should I do?

Comment: What should you do about what?

Comment: what does this do? `/\W/g.remove` also, `str.toLowerCase` does nothing too, even if you just did `str.toLowerCase()` (i.e. called the method) it still wouldn't do what you expect ... and `function palindrome(str) {{` ... you only need one `{`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Palindrome check in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813369/palindrome-check-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

here's the problems with your code

1. `function palindrome(str) {{` remove the second `{`
2. you declare `regex` but never use it
3. `/\W/g.remove;` ... what does this do? a regex doesn't have a remove property
4. `toLowerCase` is a function, that returns a new value - what you do doesn't call the function, nor does it store the result of calling the function
5. remove this line
6. OK
7. don't make this a `const` because you can't change const's - also, naming a variable the same as the function it is in can cause confusion - as you'll see
8. this will cause an infinite loop, you need `i--` to decrement `i` on each loop
9. OK
10. OK
11. OK
12. OK
13. You need to call the function - it's confusing because your variable name
14. OK
15. OK
16. OK
17. OK
18. This calls the function, but does nothing with the result

So, the resulting fixed code is:

```js
function palindrome(str) {
    let regex = /\W/g;
    str = str.toLowerCase().replace(regex, '');

    function reverseString(str) {
        let reverseString = "";
        for (let i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            reverseString += str[i];
        }
        return reverseString;
    }
    if (str === reverseString(str)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

const result = palindrome("eye");
console.log(result)
```

But, no need for that inner function

```js
function palindrome(str) {
    const regex = /\W/g;
    let reverseString = "";

    str = str.toLowerCase().replace(regex, '');

    for (let i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reverseString += str[i];
    }

    if (str === reverseString) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

const result = palindrome("eye");
console.log(result)
```

Though I'd probably write it like

```js
function palindrome(str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\W/g, '');

    return str === str.split('').reverse().join('');
}

const result = palindrome("eye");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```js
function palindrome(str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase();  //Turn everything to lower case
    str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, ''); // Remove all non alphanumeric characters.

    var revStr = str.split('');
    revStr = revStr.reverse().join('').toString();
  
    return str == revStr;

}
```

Comment: `Remove all alphanumeric characters` surely you mean NON-alphanumeric :p

Comment: I knew it was, but thought I'd point it out :p