# Reduce/concat issue when calling a property of a property that doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, concatenation

If "a_b" does not exist then the following code throws back undefined - which is what I want:

```
var abc= json.reduce((a,c) => a.concat({xyz:c.a_b}), [])
```

However, if I do the following code and look for "media" within "a_b" that does not exist then I get a failure "Cannot read property 'media' of undefined".

```
var abc= json.reduce((a,c) => a.concat({xyz:c.a_b.media}), [])
```

Why is this the case?

In both cases "a_b" does not exist yet it is ok with the code if I just call that but not if I try and look for a property within it.

Is there a way to get around this?

For example, I am trying to use "|| null" but that doesn't seem to work within a concat, as below.

```
var abc= json.reduce((a,c) => a.concat({xyz:c.a_b.media || null}), [])
```

Comment: Try `c.a_b && c.a_b.media`

Comment: @GabrielBleu, really u can't see my answer

Comment: @youne your answer is fine, but you do not cover the `|| null`

Comment: @GabrielBleu, does your comment cover it, or you just copy and past

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript AND operator within assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163407/javascript-and-operator-within-assignment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `concat` method it will create a new array instance, use `push` instead:

```
var abc = json.reduce((a, c) => {
      a.push({ xyz: c.a_b && c.a_b.media });
      return a;
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply -the && was actually the solution  -
 I did just needed to add "xyz:c.a_b&&c.a_b.media" in the concat - so I didn't need to change anything except adding the && while keeping the concat

Comment: @YouneL `concat` makes no difference here since the new array is returned.

Comment: @GabrielBleu of course, using concat or push result to the same thing, but concat will create a new array instance every time in each iteration and return it, however push will use the same array reference. check this [benchmark](https://jsperf.com/javascript-array-concat-vs-push)

Comment: @younel yes, instead of answering the question, you are suggesting an optimization, you should edit to make it clear.