# Explain a piece of JavaScript code that uses the && operator?

Tags: javascript

I am a little confused with this piece of code. I would really appreciate a step by step walk-through.

```
 i = 0;
 !(i % 3 && i % 5) && arr.push(i), i++
```

Comment: To clarify - what don't you understand about it?

Comment: not ( even % 3 && even % 3 )  and (so do) arr.push(i), i= i+1

Comment: `i = 0; if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) { arr.push(i); } i++;`

Comment: && operator is evaluate the sides of conditions true && true , false&& true , so if !(i % 3 && i % 5)  it will go to  evaluate && arr.push(i) and , is concatenation for declaration next statement  for separation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript AND operator within assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163407/javascript-and-operator-within-assignment)

Answer (score 0):

A step by step walkthrough:

```
i = 0; // assignment of 0 to the global variable i//
!// the opposite of the following expression, note does not apply to
//expression not in parentheses below // 
(i % 3 && i % 5) // returns
//true if i does  
// equal zero for both i % 3 and i % 5 // in javascript 0 is a falsy 
//value
&& arr.push(i) // returns true if the length property of arr is not
// 0, i++
```