# What does this javascript return statement mean?

Tags: javascript, return

Please take a look at this `return` statement :

```
sortedNotes() {
      return (
        this.notes &&
        this.notes.sort((a, b) => {
          const aDate = new Date(a.createdAt)
          const bDate = new Date(b.createdAt)
          return bDate - aDate
        })
      )
    }
```

What does it mean?  Isn't that enough to be just like this :

```
sortedNotes() {
      return this.notes.sort((a, b) => {
          const aDate = new Date(a.createdAt)
          const bDate = new Date(b.createdAt)
          return bDate - aDate
        })
    }
```

**Update:**

To be more clear look at this:

```
return (foo && bar);
```

what does this mean? If `foo` is true then return `bar` ??  then what about this:

```
return (bar && foo);
```

What exactly is returned here?

Comment: No, because if `this.notes` is null or undefined you get an error when you try to call the missing sort method. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163407/javascript-and-operator-within-assignment

Comment: @Nina what does this have to do with ASI?

Comment: In short, the first one firstly checks for the existence of `notes`, while the second ones doesn't... in this last case, if `notes` is `undefined` (or `null`), the code will break, because `sort` cannot be called on `undefined`.

Comment: the second returns `undefined`. wihtout the rest. that's becuase the first has parentheses.

Comment: as it stands, the second never reaches `this.notes.sort ...`.

Comment: @NinaScholz yeah you're right :)

Comment: @NinaScholz oh I see what you mean, but I doubt that's what the OP is asking about; I don't think they've run the second example.

Comment: @NinaScholz  you mean in the first example the `notes` will never be sorted?

Comment: i am speaking of the **second example**. the first one depends on the existence of `this.notes`.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the typo that causes ASI problem in the second example by the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this.notes &&` ensures that `this.notes` exists first. If it doesn't exist, it'll return without throwing an error (to be more precise, it'll return the falsey value of `this.notes` - probably `undefined`).

If you unconditionally returned `this.notes.sort`, an error will be thrown if `this.notes` is not an array. For example:

```js
class Notes {
  sortedNotes() {
    return (
      this.notes &&
      this.notes.sort((a, b) => {
        const aDate = new Date(a.createdAt)
        const bDate = new Date(b.createdAt)
        return bDate - aDate
      })
    )
  }
}

const n = new Notes();
// this.notes doesn't exist yet, so this doesn't do anything, but at least it doesn't throw an error:
n.sortedNotes();
console.log('done');
```

```js
class Notes {
  sortedNotes() {
    return (
      this.notes.sort((a, b) => {
        const aDate = new Date(a.createdAt)
        const bDate = new Date(b.createdAt)
        return bDate - aDate
      })
    )
  }
}

const n = new Notes();
// Throws:
n.sortedNotes();
console.log('done');
```

So the test for `this.notes`' existence is needed to avoid an error when `this.notes` doesn't exist when `sortedNotes` is called.

It may have just been a typo, but make sure that *something* follows the `return` statement other than a plain newline - either use `return this.notes.sort((a, b) => {`, or put an opening parentheses `(` right after it, to avoid ASI problems. (otherwise, nothing will be returned)

---

`return (foo && bar);`

means: Evaluate `foo`. If it is truthy, evaluate `bar` and return `bar`. Otherwise, return `foo`.

`return (bar && foo);`

means: Evaluate `bar`. If it is truthy, evaluate `foo` and return `foo`. Otherwise, return `bar`.

In your context, a more accurate minimal example would be when it's not known whether a property exists yet. Eg

```
return obj.fn()
```

will throw if `obj` is undefined, whereas

```
return obj && obj.fn();
```

will not throw.

All this said, this is *odd* code to write. It would be much more readable to have an explicit test instead, eg something like:

```
if (!obj) {
  return 'Not defined yet!';
} else {
  return obj.fn();
}
```

Comment: as [`@nina`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58196691/what-does-this-javascript-retern-statement-mean#comment102771994_58196691) pointed out in comments in the second snippet of OP's code it won't even `reach to this.notes.sort`, since you added `()` around the return so that behavior cannot be observed in your code, but this will happen in OP's code

Comment: Thank you! I fixed the typo for `ASI` problems.  I kinda figure it out myself but I am confused!  My question is: does the first example in my question event sort the `notes` array if it is not `undefined`?   See the updated part of the question.