# If condition does not validate for both conditions

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, dom

So I am doing some form validation and I am trying to take user input that only calls the function once both conditions have been met. So far it seems that only the first condition being met will result in a "Works" alert while the second condition does not need to be satisfied. I could input the ~ to try and satisfy the second condition but it will still give me the "Broken" alert. I'm not sure if I can just combine both link1 and link2 into one condition where my function will check for the input to start with http:// but also check for a ~ in the url somewhere.

```
  var link1 = /[~]/;
  var link2 = /^http:\/\//;

  var input = document.getElementsByName("textbox")[0];
  if(input.value.match(link1 && link2)) {
  alert("Works");
   } else {
  alert("Broken");
   }
```

Comment: The value of `link1 && link2` is `/^http:\/\//`. You're not checking the first condition at all.

Answer (score 1):

`input.value.match` takes one argument, you cannot pass 2 values at the same time in it. you will need to have them checked separately like this:

```
  if(input.value.match(link1) && input.value.match(link2) )
```

Comment: OP isn't passing a *boolean* in… :-3

Comment: if(value)  checks the existence.. && brings the comparison which will result in boolean resultant in JS, Please correct me. Thanks. @deceze

Comment: Javascript's `&&` *does not return a boolean*: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3163422/476

Answer (score 0):

**Check like this. it would meet if the both conditions are true**

```
     if(input.value.match(link1) && input.value.match(link2)) {
        alert("Works");
     }
     else {
        alert("Broken");
     }
```