# Unsure as to what this formatting means

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am fairly new to JavaScript and am going over some code. However there is one bit i am unsure about.

```
product = product !== null && product[0] !== null && product[0].id || "";
```

Where product is an array. Could someone please help me understand what this does. Any help would be much appreciated. Many thanks =)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript AND operator within assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163407/javascript-and-operator-within-assignment)

Comment: Also relevant [JavaScript OR (||) variable assignment explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation) [What does the construct x = x || y mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-the-construct-x-x-y-mean)

Comment: It helps, however I am still slightly confused by the statement especially when theres multiple "and"s and an "or"

Comment: @jknotek That's not correct. The `&&` operator evaluates to the last operand evaluated. If the first operand is falsy, it returns the first operand (`0 && true` → `0`). If the first operand is truthy, it returns the second operand (`true && 1` → `1`; `true && null` → `null`).

Comment: @JordanRunning Ah yes, thank you for the correction.

Comment: With [optional chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) the equivalent would be `product = product?.[0]?.id || ''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to understand what this does it to run it and observe the result.

Here's a JSBin showing 3 examples - which produce a different outcome, depending on the initial value of `product` - https://jsbin.com/roruvecubi/edit?js,console

To further clarify this with an explanation...

It will attempt to evaluate that all the following premises are `true` at the same time and re-assign `product` to the value of `id` of the first object found (if these are found) or an empty string if otherwise.

1. `product` array is NOT `null`

AND

2. First element of `product` array is NOT `null`

AND

3. First element of `product` array is an object containing a truthy key-value pair with key `id`. I.e. First element could like this:

```
 { 
   id: "someValue" // product[0].id would be a truthy value in this case 
 }
```

AND

4. If 3.0 is `true` - assign value of `id`. If 3.0 is NOT `true` (id: does not contain a truthy `object`, `array`, `number`, `string`, `true` - Google the precise definition of `truthy`), then just assign empty string `""` and thus result will be `product = ""`;

Comment: Thats exactly the helping hand i was looking for, many thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

1. product !== null it checks if product is null if it is it will stop right here and not do the other calculations (this is practiced so you won't get undefined, in this case, hmm null)
2. product[0] !== null  checks if null, so when .id you won't get an error can't find id of undefined / null

   ```
   let usr = null
   console.log(usr.id)
   ```

   GIVES ERROR Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null

With a few words, these are some practices **to check if the VARIABLE has unwanted values to stop the calculations right there and not get *errors***.
Some prefer to try catch v--