# Execute function conditionally with && syntax JS

Tags: javascript

Can I execute functions this way?

```
const test = testFunc() // returns "value" or undefined

test && anotherFunction()
```

Basically I want to execute `anotherFunction()` if test const is defined, otherwise just skip it.

I know that I can use something like this:

```
if (test) {
    anotherFunction()
}
```

but I'm interested why the first method isn't working.

I will appreciate if someone explain me the difference between `if () {}` and `&&`.

// I'm confused because if I trying to use the first method I get:

```
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression
```

in my IDE.

Comment: If `testFunc()` returns `undefined` then `anotherFunction()` will not be called.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the behavior that I expecting

Comment: @jay_dtr And that is the behavior you get. So what is your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript AND operator within assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163407/javascript-and-operator-within-assignment)

Comment: You're likely just thinking `testFunc()` is returning something, even though it's not. If you're not sure, put its code in a snippet and edit your post.

Comment: @Ivar `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression` in my IDE if I use the first method

Comment: Then the problem is your IDE, not your code.

Comment: @jay_dtr [I cannot replicate that](https://jsfiddle.net/bqj3f5t7/1/).

Comment: It is a rule with your linter. It is expecting the value to be stored into a variable. So if you want to use that pattern change the rule in your linter https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions

Comment: @epascarello, you are right, this is probably the case. But the question remains - can I use it like this, or it is not a good practice?

Comment: You can use it if you change your linter to allow it. The page has the settings to enable to allow that syntax.

Comment: @jay_dtr If you have to read through a lot of code and come across this part, which of those would you find more clear/obvious?

Comment: @Andrew if you got help on the below answer, kindly accept and vote so it will be helpful for future reference 

Answer (score 1):

The approach will work as expected you can see the below two cases as you mentioned.

**First Case** - testFunc returns some value

```js
const testFunc = () => 1

const anotherFunction = () => 2

const test = testFunc()

test && anotherFunction()
```

**Second Case** - testFunc returns undefined

```js
const testFunc = () => undefined

const anotherFunction = () => 2

const test = testFunc() 

test && anotherFunction()
```

I hope this will help to understand it better.

Comment: Your second case looks exactly the same as the first case