# Keep original value with "variable = NEWVAR || variable;"

Tags: javascript, variables

Is this a legitimate way to update variables and keep the original value if the new value is undefined?

```
variable = NEWVAR || variable;
```

I created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cusVE/) and so far it looks fine, but I don't want to get any nasty surprises.

Here is a test case:

```
var test = "hello";

test = undefined || test;

alert('"' + test + '"');
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446433/how-does-javascript-logical-assignment-work

Comment: It will keep the original if NEWVAR is undefined or null but also if NEWVAR is 0, false and the empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, yes, i use it quite often. But you have to keep in mind that

Douglas Crockford: Javascript The Good Parts (p. 40)

> The || operator produces the value of its first operand if the first operand is truthy. Otherwise, it produces the
>   value of the second operand.

So if `NEWVAR` contains any falsy (`false`,`null`,`undefined`,`NaN`,`0`,`""`) value, the second opertand is evaluated.

As long as you are aware of this you can always use the `||` operator to get default values

Douglas Crockford: Javascript The Good Parts (p. 51)

> The || operator can be used to fill in default values:

```
var middle = stooge["middle-name"] || "(none)";
var status = flight.status || "unknown";
```

Comment: Thanks, falsy values are ok for me, since I want to keep the original value in that case too

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. It technically works, but you have to be careful of [falsy values](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript) because if `NEWVAR` is `0`, `false`, `""`, or any other falsy value, it won't be assigned. A wiser way to do this would be to check whether or not `NEWVAR` is defined, perhaps with a tertiary operator:

```
variable = (typeof NEWVAR === "undefined") ? variable : NEWVAR;
```

Comment: wouldn't typeof return something like "Object", "Array" etc... I think you meant `typeof NEWVAR !== 'undefined'`

Comment: @eis: Whoops, missed that. Thanks.

Comment: You can see it the other way round either, this can come in pretty handy if you don't want **any falsy** value e.g `""` to be assigned.

It's more about keeping in mind what evaluates `falsy`


Oh and @ElliotBonneville isnt this a `ternary` operator ? =)

Comment: @eis: Thanks for the edit, but you've got it backwards. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KYhYY/). :)

Comment: @ElliotBonneville yeah, misread the intent of OP. Used to backwards way of using.