# What does "||" refer to in JavaScript apart from Or?

Tags: javascript

I was recently going through some JavaScript code (written by someone else) and it had something like this:

```
var exports = exports || null;
```

What does this mean? Is this the equivalent of:

```
var exports = exports ? exports : null;
```

Comment: Yes. They both are equivalent.

Comment: Yes. Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR

Comment: It _still_ means *or* in that example. exports or null.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446433/how-does-javascript-logical-assignment-work

Comment: @Tushar: One significant difference is that `exports` is only evaluated once in the `||` case, but twice in the conditional operator case. Doesn't matter for the above, of course, but `var x = a() || b();` is very different from `var x = a() ? a() : b();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does “||” refer to in JavaScript apart from Or?

Nothing, but its definition of "or" is not the same as some other languages.

The `||`operator evaluates its left-hand operand and if that result is *truthy*, that's the result of the operation; otherwise, the right-hand operand is evaluated and that result is the result of the operation.

So it doesn't necessarily result in a boolean value. In your example, `exports || null` will be the value of `exports` if it's truthy, or `null` if it isn't.