# Variable equals to A || B. How does this work?

Tags: javascript

I came across this code:

```
function extend(out){
    out = out || {};
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
        var obj = arguments[i];
        if (!obj) continue;
        for (var key in obj){
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
                out[key] = (typeof obj[key] === 'object') ? extend(out[key], obj[key]) : obj[key];
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

What does the line `out = out || {};` mean and how does it work?

This function bascially combines different objects into one object.

Comment: This question been asked before!

Comment: Could you provide a link please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2100758/6647153

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/q/4446433/6647153 is exactly your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sets a default value for `out`, ie if out is not provided to the function, (or it is a falsy value such as `false`, `0`, `null`, `undefined` or `''`), then out is assigned `{}`.

How it works:
Javascript uses [short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation), which means the the or (`||`) operator will return the first non-falsy value. If `out` is not falsy, nothing changes, if out is falsy, it gets set to `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, the `||` operator returns the first operand if it is a truthy value; otherwise, it returns the second. So in context here, if `out` is a falsy value (such as `undefined`), then `out = out || {}` will assign `{}` to `out`; otherwise, it will assign the current value of `out` into `out`, which effectively does nothing.

The intent is to provide a default value for `out`. If the caller passes `false`, `null`, or `undefined` as the first argument, then `out` will be a new object. If the caller passes an object as the first argument, then the function will modify that object.

Answer (score 0):

It is basically the short hand of doing this

```
if(!out){
    out = {};
}
```

Essentially if out does not evaluate to 'true' then out will be set to an empty array in this case.

Already answered here also: [What does the construct x = x || y mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-the-construct-x-x-y-mean)

Comment: That's a empty object, not an array.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct, I've been working in C# all week.

Answer (score 0):

That is a simplified form of this:

```
function extend(out){
    if (!out) {
        out = {};
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
out = out || {};
```

If the variable 'out' is not set prior to this line, the value will be set to an empty array. [JavaScript OR (||) variable assignment explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation)