# ReactJS statement name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a project using ReactJS and I am using a statement, but I do not know the name of it.

Here is a bit of my code so it might make sense.

```
function Login(props) {
            return (
                <form>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="username"
                        onChange={e=>props.app.setState({"username":e.currentTarget.value})}
                        value={props.app.state.username}
                    />
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="password"
                        onChange={e=>props.app.setState({"password":e.currentTarget.value})}
                        value={props.app.state.password}
                    />
                    <button type="button" onClick={_=>props.app.loadTasks()}>Login</button>
                    {props.app.state.logged_in == -1 && <p className="error">Incorrect username or password</p>}
                    {props.app.state.logged_in >= -1 && <title>Task Keeper</title>}
                </form>
            );
        }
```

The exact thing I need a name for is this line here:

```
{props.app.state.logged_in == -1 && <p className="error">Incorrect username or password</p>}
{props.app.state.logged_in >= -1 && <title>Task Keeper</title>}
```

Like I am using them and I don't even know what they are called. And if possible explain how is working? I am only assuming is working like an **if statement.**

Comment: Does this post answers to your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446433/how-does-javascript-logical-assignment-work

Comment: In JSX, this is known as [inline conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, an explanation of how this works, because it can be quite confusing when you're starting. When you do:

```
{props.app.state.logged_in >= -1 && <title>Task Keeper</title>}
```

You're telling React to render the result of the following operation:

```
props.app.state.logged_in >= -1
AND
<title>Task Keeper</title>
```

The ending result is that if `props.app.state.logged_in >= -1` is true, then

```
<title>Task Keeper</title>
```

is rendered, and if not, then nothing is rendered. That is similar to telling React:

```
if (props.app.state.logged_in >= -1)
    <title>Task Keeper</title>
```

Now as to what to call that concept in general, I'd say it's just conditional rendering. It works that way because of a quirk in javascript:

`&&` evaluates as the left hand side if the left hand side is `false`, otherwise it evaluates as the right hand side. Meaning that `true && expression` is equal to `expression`, and `false && expression` is equal to `false`. In general, The value of the `&&` expression is the value of the subexpression last evaluated. This way of doing things is called short circuit evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called [Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) and is analyzed really good on the MDN web docs.