# (Multiple) Replace string with array

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have a large string which need be replaced a few times. Such as

```
var str="Username:[UN] Location:[LC] Age:[AG] ... "

str=str.replace("[UN]","Ali")
str=str.replace("[LC]","Turkey")
str=str.replace("[AG]","29")
...
//lots of replace
...
```

Is there a way to put those FIND and REPLACE parameters to an array, and replace all of them at once? Such as:

```
reps = [["UN","Ali"], ["LC","Turkey"], ["AG","29"], ...]
$(str).replace(reps)
```

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski it should be the other way around since this one is older than your duplicate proposal

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No jQuery is required.

```
var reps = {
  UN: "Ali",
  LC: "Turkey",
  AG: "29",
  ...
};

return str.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, function(s, key) {
   return reps[key] || s;
});
```

- The regex `/\[(\w+)\]/g` finds all substrings of the form `[XYZ]`.
- Whenever such a pattern is found, the function in the 2nd parameter of `.replace` will be called to get the replacement.
- It will search the associative array and try to return that replacement if the key exists (`reps[key]`).
- Otherwise, the original substring (`s`) will be returned, i.e. nothing is replaced. (See [In Javascript, what does it mean when there is a logical operator in a variable declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088098/in-javascript-what-does-it-mean-when-there-is-a-logical-operator-in-a-variable-d) for how `||` makes this work.)

Comment: +1, although: This assumes the replacement will never be an empty string. @user: If sometimes the replacements are empty strings, change the body of the function to `var rep = reps[key]; return typeof rep === "undefined" ? s : rep;`

Comment: Just tried it in Chrome's console, it doesn't work. `var reps = {
  UN: "Ali",
  LC: "Turkey",
  AG: "29"
};`, then `var str = "hello UN, I'm in LC, AG"`, and finally `str.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, function(s, key) {
   return reps[key] || s;
});` returns the inital string, without any replacement.

Comment: @maxagaz Please check OP's question, the `str` is `var str = "Username:[UN] Location:[LC] Age:[AG]"`. There are brackets around the UN, LC and AG.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
var array = {"UN":"ALI", "LC":"Turkey", "AG":"29"};

for (var val in array) {
  str = str.split(val).join(array[val]);
}
```