# what does "window.gapi = window.gapi || {};" mean?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm a little confused with the syntax here.

```
window.foo = window.bar || {};
```

Any ideas? I'm just trying to understand javaScript better. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "var FOO = FOO || {}" mean in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439579/what-does-var-foo-foo-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088098/in-javascript-what-does-it-mean-when-there-is-a-logical-operator-in-a-variable-d

Comment: Ah. Yeah I checked those out too and they're also very helpful. I suppose not quite understanding the concept makes it hard to understand how to formulate a question. Thanks for the help! Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `window.bar` is null or undefined (also: `0`, `""`, `NaN` and `false`) then `window.foo` will be set to an empty object (`{}`), otherwise it will be `window.bar`.

The logical OR operator (`||`) works as a null coalescing operator in this situation. It's basically shorthand for:

```
window.foo = (window.bar != null ? window.bar : {});
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/null-coalescing-operator-for-javascript/476445#476445) explains the behavior in more detail.

Comment: If window.bar is __falsy__ (which includes but is not limited to null and undefined) then window.foo will be set to an empty object.

Comment: Why would a developer want to do that, though?  Just so it doesn't throw an undefined error?

Comment: @Netside: I think normally you wouldn't have two separate variables here. A normal use case would be `window.foo = window.foo || {}`. This simply prevents redefining `window.foo` in case you ran a script twice, or ensures that it is defined for some other script that might depend on it.

Comment: @Cory I understand.  Thank you, also.