# Javascript Namespacing / best practices

Tags: javascript, namespaces

```
var google = google || {};
google.Test = google.Test || {};
google.Test.Render = google.Test.Render || {};
```

What is the difference between the above, and the following.

`var MyCompany = MyCompany || {
    MyApplication: {
        Model: {}
    }  };`

And what is the purpose of the || ?

Comment: The or basically says, if `google` is null, make the `sample` variable an empty object, rather than setting it to null as well.  If `MyCompany` is null, set it to this new object with `MyApplication` in it

Comment: testing like this `x = x || ...` is dangerous, since `0` and `""` will be overridden too, which sometimes might be a valid value.

Comment: @Christoph: Not in this context though.

Comment: I changed `var sample = google` to `var google = google` so the example makes sense.

Comment: @FelixKling That's why i said sometimes... I think it's important to know, since this method is quite common to set default values for params nowadays.

Comment: doesn't this throw a ReferenceError because google is used before it is defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first snippet tests whether each level of the namespace exists and if not, it creates it (though the first line should probably be `var google = google || {};`).

The second one only tests whether the top level exists. For example:

```
var MyCompany = {};

// later in the same scope

var MyCompany = MyCompany || { MyApplication: { Model: {} } };
```

Since `MyCompany` is already defined, this expression evaluates to `MyCompany = MyCompany`, i.e. `MyCompany` stays an empty element, the nested objects are not created. If the following code relies on `MyCompany.MyApplication`'s existence, it will fail.

How `||` works is described here: [In Javascript, what does it mean when there is a logical operator in a variable declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088098/in-javascript-what-does-it-mean-when-there-is-a-logical-operator-in-a-variable)

Comment: Although if the first test fails, no other levels will exist either so there is no need to test them. F.ex `google = google ? (function() { // test other levels and return google }()) : {};`

Comment: @David: Ah, you mean if the expression evaluates to `google = {}`? Yes, in that case you would not have to test the existence of the other levels, since they cannot exist, but it's a compact way of creating the namespace. It avoids nasty `if-else` statements and repetition.