# Can someone please explain e = e || x? Why assign e to e?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

Can anyone explain what this statement means?

```
e = e || x
```

Specifically,

```
e = e || window.event
```

This appears in a chunk of code I am looking at.

I'm not at a complete loss, however My understanding is that it assigns both `e` and `window.event` (or x/whatever) to e. It's only natural, right?

But what is the value in assigning `e` to `e`? Shouldn't `e = window.event` be enough? Perhaps is depends on how it is used?

Comment: Isn't `||` a boolean operator? So `e` should be either `true` or `false` after this?

Comment: it's "use e if it's already defined/available, otherwise use x". It's a nice bit of syntactical sugar in javascript, in pseudo-code, "if (exists e) then return e else return x".

Comment: @Cobra_Fast `||` doesn't return true / false in javascript, it returns the first object that is "truthy".

Comment: IE doesn't pass the event argument to the handler

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript OR (||) variable assignment explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation)

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Javascript, what does it mean when there is a logical operator in a variable declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088098/in-javascript-what-does-it-mean-when-there-is-a-logical-operator-in-a-variable) (The possible dupe was itself a possible dupe!)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`e = e || x` assigns `x` to `e` if `e` evalutes to false.

This is the same as:

```
if (!e) {
  e = x;
}
// or
e = e ? e : x
```

Here is a table which shows which values evalute to *false*: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7615236/603003

The most important values are: *null* and *undefined*.

---

What does it mean in your context?
You probably have some sort of this code:

```
function handler(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
}
```

Where `handler` is an event listener attached to a DOM element. Since older versions of IE did not pass the event object as a parameter, one had to check if the parameter was *undefined*. If the latter was the case, one assigns the global `window.event` object (which IE supplied) to `e`.

Comment: Yikes! I feel silly, I should have remembered that. It's so simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't assign *both* to "e", just the one that's not either `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `NaN`, `""`, or `false`. It prefers the original value of "e" to `window.event` because "e" is on the left side of `||`, but if it's empty (one of those values I listed) then "e" will be assigned `window.event`.

It's done because Internet Explorer didn't pass the event reference as a parameter, instead simply binding to a global symbol. Event handlers were very often written:

```
function someHandler(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  // ...
}
```

It would probably have been more rigorously "correct" to write:

```
function pedanticHandler(e) {
  if (e === undefined) // or arguments.length == 0 perhaps
    e = window.event;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Specifically, if e has a value, it keeps its value. If it is undefined, we look elsewhere for a value.

Comment: @JonKiparsky yes, expanded :)

Comment: @VivinPaliath Yes, it is! (... but only if someone in your team really declares the variable `undefined` ;) ).

Comment: @CrazyTrain I think he (including me) compared `typeof e === "undefined"` to `e === undefined`, not to `if (e)` in general.

Comment: Please take all extended discussions to chat. This is not a good place for them. If you have clarifications for the question or an answer, please edit that post with the relevant information.

Comment: @CrazyTrain [Chat is here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33502/testing-for-undefined) I am deleting my comments.

Answer (score 4):

You're misunderstanding operators.

This line assigns the **expression** `e || x` to the variable  `e`.

The value of `e || x` is the first truthy value.
If `e` is truthy, that will be `e`; if `e` is falsy, it will be `x`.

Answer (score 2):

it is redundant to assign `e = e`, they do it as part of this statement because it is an idiom.

The statement checks if `e` is defined and if it is not then it initializes it with the expression that follows `||`. This works because when `||` expression is evaluated the interpreter stops evaluation when the first `true` part (from the left) is found.

In particular, if `e` evaluates to `true` then evaluation stops right then and effectively you have `e = e`, which is redundant. But if `e` is undefined or evaluates to `false` then the right part of the `||` is evaluated  and assigned to `e`.

I personally would use an `if` statement instead of being clever. Or restructure the code even more to avoid `if` altogether.

EDIT: I think the original code is buggy. Clearly the intention is check if `e` is already initialized. But here it can be reassigned to itself if it is already initialized and evaluates to `true`. This can have unwanted side effects.

Comment: then why do you think it's redundant? have you drive an old IE lately?

Comment: There's no misunderstanding of the code, it just looks that way from how the answer is phrased.  It should have been written like this: "Of course it is redundant to assign `e` to `e`; that's not what this code does.  Instead, the programmer is doing something else: namely assigning a value to `e` only if `e` is falsy.  This idiom saves code over the longer `if (!e) e = x` style.

Comment: The phrasing of this answer is poor. I'm sure akonsu knows what it does, but answering isn't just about knowing. It's about communicating. Basically, the first sentence makes no sense. If it's redundant, how is it saving code?

Comment: @CrazyTrain Very true.  It's not a good answer by any means.  I hope i t gets edited.  I just wanted to share what I discovered after puzzling over it for a couple minutes, because it wasn't obvious even after several reads. :)

Comment: I think this answer is valuable because it describes the purpose behind OPs code.

Comment: `if e is defined then evaluation stops right then and effectively you have e = e` That is wrong! It must say: `if e is defined **and** evalutes to true`.

Comment: @akonsu But I don't think that such code is buggy or unintended. It is indeed a very useful technique IMHO. Major projects do use it, too, jQuery uses it for example in [this file](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/6b5391508e7354076a32375c7f536f8eb91195ee/src/event.js).

Answer (score 2):

If `e` is `undefined` (or `null`, or any other `false` value), it is initialized with `x`.

It is implicitly :

```
var e = e ? e : x;
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't assign both values to `e`. It's just a way of assigning `x` to `e` if the original value of `e` is `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `false`, `NaN`, or an empty string (`""`). If the original value of `e` doesn't match any of the aforementioned conditions, it keeps the original value.

Basically, it's a shorthand form for:

```
if(!e) {
   e = x;
}
```

Comment: @Virus721 Thanks! Added that to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer (ComFreek) is correct.  The *reason* it does this is because of lazy evaluation.  The boolean `x || y`, evaluated lazily will check `x` first.  If it evaluates to `TRUE` (i.e. is non-zero, non-null), then the expression stops and returns TRUE.  If `x` evaluates to `FALSE`, it will return `y`.

This is clever code.  Clever is stupid. (opinion)
As a maintainer, I prefer to see

```
if (!e) {
    e = x;
}
```

Comment: Agreed. C# has a slightly better notation with e = e ?? x; The double quesiton mark makes it more clear that your checking whether something exists, rather than assigning a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

It set e equal to either itself (if it is not null, undefined or false) otherwise window.event.

It is like saying

```
if (!e) e = window.event;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example `e = e || window.event;` is equivalent to :

```
if(!e){
     e = window.event;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you add an eventhandler to an element

```
document.addEventListener('click',handler,false);
```

in most browsers it passes the event as first parameter.

```
handler=function(e){// e is the event in some browsers
 e=e||window.event; // but in some old browsers the event is window.event
  // so you check if e(event) exists else you use window.event.
  // '||' means or...
  // e is already defined as a placeholder in the handler function
  // so you don't need to put var infront of it
}
```