# Javascript || syntax for functions

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand the below block of syntax (taken from angular docs to represent the use of angular noop as an 'empty' function)

```
function foo(callback) {
  var result = calculateResult();
  (callback || angular.noop)(result);
}
```

I don't understand the '||'  syntax. I tried looking it up but had trouble searching and wasn't really sure what to search.

Thinking of it as 'OR' syntax, it would mean to me if a function was assigned to the callback or if the function was assigned to angular noop would equal true and then a function is being called on true. But obviously that's wrong

Apologies in advance for the newbishness of the question.

`- EDIT -`

To clarify further, I'm aware of what it does guessing from the example. However, I'm trying to figure out what javascripts rule say that would cause the return statement for `(callback1 || callback2)` to return a function object instead of a boolean (as implied by the fact that in the example you can call the return of the sub-expression).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bit

```
(callback || angular.noop)(result);
```

is short for:

```
if (callback) { 
    callback(result); 
} else {
    angular.noop(result); 
}
```

It takes advantage of the fact that `||` is lazily executed. The search term you're looking for is [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation). To explain the "why" on how this works, we can take a look at the ECMAScript specification, specifically [11.11 Binary Logical Operators](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.11),

> The value produced by a `&&` or `||` operator is not necessarily of type `Boolean`. The value produced will always be the value of one of the two operand expressions. Note that this doesn't mean that you can't depend on an expression such as:

```
if (a || b) // <-- logical expression will evaluate to the value of a or b, NOT true or false
```

because JavaScript evaluates boolean values as truthy or falsy, formally defined as the operation `ToBoolean()` in the ECMAScript specification.

From 9.2 ToBoolean

> The abstract operation ToBoolean converts its argument to a value of type Boolean according to Table 11:

```
 Argument         
   Type           Result

 Undefined        false
 Null             false
 Boolean          The result equals the input argument (no conversion).
 Number           The result is false if the argument is +0, −0, or NaN; 
                      otherwise the result is true.
 String           The result is false if the argument is the empty String 
                      (its length is zero); otherwise the result is true.
 Object           True
```

Comment: with your help I think I figured out my issue. Could you please mention that the return for an || operation is not a bool but the actual value just for reference? I'll accept your answer in advance.

Comment: @ThinkBonobo Top answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088098/in-javascript-what-does-it-mean-when-there-is-a-logical-operator-in-a-variable explains it more succinctly than I would

Answer (score 5):

Basically the statement

`(callback || angular.noop)(result);`

Can be read as:

Call the function `callback` or `angular.noop` with the argument of `result`

If callback is not defined the OR (`||`) will be evaluated to call the `angular.noop` function passing the variable `result` to the function.

The `angular.noop()` function is a function that does nothing. More read here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.noop

Comment: Thanks. the || is actually returning a function not a boolean. Getting that piece makes the rest of it make sense to me now.